# How to check who won in rock, paper, scissors- user vs computer- Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a rock, paper scissors game- user vs computer in Python tkinter. I'm struggling in the check function- the if statements in that function always evaluate to false for some reason (I checked by adding an else statement and printing something, and the program ended up going to the else statement every time). Can someone help me construct better if statements that check who won?
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
window.geometry("800x600+220+10")
window.configure(bg="#fbfcbc")

title = Label(window, text="Rock Paper Scissors:\nUser vs. Computer", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), fg="#f59c97",
              bg="#fbfcbc")
title.place(x=200, y=10)
count = 0
computer_choice = None
chosen = []


images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/rock.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/paper.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/scissors.png")
]


def user_choice():
    global count

    user_choice_button.configure(text="", image=images_list[count])
    user_choice_button.place(x=120, y=320)
    count += 1

    if count == 3:
        count = 0


def start():
    global computer_choice

    try:
        while chosen[-1] == computer_choice:
            computer_choice = images_list[randint(0, 2)]
        chosen.append(computer_choice)
    except IndexError:
        computer_choice = images_list[randint(0, 2)]
        chosen.append(computer_choice)

    computer_choice_label.configure(image=computer_choice, text="")
    check()


def check():
    if user_choice_button["image"] == images_list[0] and computer_choice_label["image"] == images_list[1]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == images_list[1] and computer_choice_label["image"] == images_list[0]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == images_list[0] and computer_choice_label["image"] == images_list[2]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == images_list[2] and computer_choice_label["image"] == images_list[0]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == images_list[1] and computer_choice_label["image"] == images_list[2]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == images_list[2] and computer_choice_label["image"] == images_list[1]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == computer_choice_label["image"]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The game ended in a draw!")


def reset():
    user_choice_button.configure(text="Click to\nchoose", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40))
    user_choice_button.place(x=50, y=300)
    computer_choice_label.configure(text="The computer's\nchoice will be\ndisplayed here",
                                    font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30))
    computer_choice_label.place(x=450, y=310)


user_choice_button = Button(window, text="Click to\nchoose", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40), bg="#b6f5f8",
                            fg="#f59c97", command=user_choice)
user_choice_button.place(x=50, y=300)
computer_choice_label = Label(window, text="The computer's\nchoice will be\ndisplayed here",
                              font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), bg="#fbfcbc", fg="#f59c97")
computer_choice_label.place(x=450, y=310)
start_button = Button(window, text="START", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), bg="lime", command=start)
start_button.place(x=300, y=200)


window.mainloop()
```

A big thanks to jasonharper for solving the problem! Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
window.geometry("800x600+220+10")
window.configure(bg="#fbfcbc")

title = Label(window, text="Rock Paper Scissors:\nUser vs. Computer", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), fg="#f59c97",
              bg="#fbfcbc")
title.place(x=200, y=10)
count = 0
computer_choice = None
chosen = []


images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/rock.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/paper.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/scissors.png")
]


def user_choice():
    global count

    user_choice_button.configure(text="", image=images_list[count])
    user_choice_button.place(x=120, y=320)
    count += 1

    if count == 3:
        count = 0


def start():
    global computer_choice

    try:
        while chosen[-1] == computer_choice:
            computer_choice = images_list[randint(0, 2)]
        chosen.append(computer_choice)
    except IndexError:
        computer_choice = images_list[randint(0, 2)]
        chosen.append(computer_choice)

    computer_choice_label.configure(image=computer_choice, text="")
    check()


def check():
    if user_choice_button["image"] == str(images_list[0]) and computer_choice_label["image"] == str(images_list[1]):
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == str(images_list[1]) and computer_choice_label["image"] == str(images_list[0]):
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == str(images_list[0]) and computer_choice_label["image"] == str(images_list[2]):
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == str(images_list[2]) and computer_choice_label["image"] == str(images_list[0]):
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == str(images_list[1]) and computer_choice_label["image"] == str(images_list[2]):
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == str(images_list[2]) and computer_choice_label["image"] == str(images_list[1]):
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button["image"] == computer_choice_label["image"]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The game ended in a draw!")


def reset():
    user_choice_button.configure(text="Click to\nchoose", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40))
    user_choice_button.place(x=50, y=300)
    computer_choice_label.configure(text="The computer's\nchoice will be\ndisplayed here",
                                    font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30))
    computer_choice_label.place(x=450, y=310)


user_choice_button = Button(window, text="Click to\nchoose", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40), bg="#b6f5f8",
                            fg="#f59c97", command=user_choice)
user_choice_button.place(x=50, y=300)
computer_choice_label = Label(window, text="The computer's\nchoice will be\ndisplayed here",
                              font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), bg="#fbfcbc", fg="#f59c97")
computer_choice_label.place(x=450, y=310)
start_button = Button(window, text="START", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), bg="lime", command=start)
start_button.place(x=300, y=200)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I substituted the images with text, it works fine! (I don't know the images)

Comment: Can you show me the code after you substituted the images with text?

Comment: Check the answer?

Comment: Image objects are likely going to only evaluate as equivalent if they are in fact the same object. Even if they are referencing the same image. I would check to see if that is the root of the problem.

Comment: What you get back from the `"image"` option of a widget will be a string, that does NOT compare equal to the `PhotoImage` option originally used to set that option.  Compare against `str(images_list[0])`, for example, and I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
window.geometry("800x600+220+10")
window.configure(bg="#fbfcbc")

title = Label(window, text="Rock Paper Scissors:\nUser vs. Computer", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), fg="#f59c97",
              bg="#fbfcbc")
title.place(x=200, y=10)
count = 0
computer_choice = None
chosen = []


images_list = [
    "Rock",'Paper','Scissors'
]


def user_choice():
    global count

    user_choice_button.configure(text=images_list[count])
    user_choice_button.place(x=120, y=320)
    count += 1

    if count == 3:
        count = 0


def start():
    global computer_choice

    try:
        while chosen[-1] == computer_choice:
            computer_choice = images_list[randint(0, 2)]
        chosen.append(computer_choice)
    except IndexError:
        computer_choice = images_list[randint(0, 2)]
        chosen.append(computer_choice)

    computer_choice_label.configure(text=computer_choice)
    check()


def check():
    if user_choice_button['text'] == images_list[0] and computer_choice_label['text'] == images_list[1]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button['text'] == images_list[1] and computer_choice_label['text'] == images_list[0]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button['text'] == images_list[0] and computer_choice_label['text'] == images_list[2]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button['text'] == images_list[2] and computer_choice_label['text'] == images_list[0]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button['text'] == images_list[1] and computer_choice_label['text'] == images_list[2]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The computer won!")
    elif user_choice_button['text'] == images_list[2] and computer_choice_label['text'] == images_list[1]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "You won!")
    elif user_choice_button['text'] == computer_choice_label['text']:
        messagebox.showinfo("Rock, Paper, Scissors", "The game ended in a draw!")


def reset():
    user_choice_button.configure(text="Click to\nchoose", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40))
    user_choice_button.place(x=50, y=300)
    computer_choice_label.configure(text="The computer's\nchoice will be\ndisplayed here",
                                    font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30))
    computer_choice_label.place(x=450, y=310)


user_choice_button = Button(window, text="Click to\nchoose", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40), bg="#b6f5f8",
                            fg="#f59c97", command=user_choice)
user_choice_button.place(x=50, y=300)
computer_choice_label = Label(window, text="The computer's\nchoice will be\ndisplayed here",
                              font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), bg="#fbfcbc", fg="#f59c97")
computer_choice_label.place(x=450, y=310)
start_button = Button(window, text="START", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), bg="lime", command=start)
start_button.place(x=300, y=200)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Roni, please [edit] the question to include the images?

Comment: How do you include the images in the question? I'm new to Stack Overflow so I don't know how

Comment: Copy the image, paste it in the text box where you write the function. Also, there is a option to insert image included in the text box were you write the question @Roni

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to help though!

Comment: No problem @Roni